# Как "разбить" переменные?

Tags: python, переменные

Делал заготовку для простой функции, которая ищет ближайший квадрат к заданному числу. По задумке, должна работать с очень большими числами (иначе я бы просто посчитал на калькуляторе).

Вот сама заготовка:

```
def find_closest_square(x):
    pr = -1
    sq = 0
    for i in range(x):
        pr = sq
        sq = i ** i
        print pr, sq
```

Вот результат вызова в интерпретаторе:

```
In [2]: squares.find_closest_square(10)
0 1
1 1
1 4
4 27
27 256
256 3125
3125 46656
46656 823543   
823543 16777216
16777216 387420489
```

Происходит так, видимо, из-за того, что в итоге две переменные ссылаются на одно значение, как это исправить? В доках сходу я этого не нашёл.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что Ваша функция должна так работать:

    f(6) => 4
    f(15) => 16
    f(98) => 100

или напишите правильные результаты.

Comment: Какие исходящие данные Вы ожидали увидеть при вызове squares.find_closest_square(10)?

Comment: В данном варианте она должна выдавать 

    In: f(4)
    Out: 0 1
        1 4
        4 9
        9 16

Вообще суть введения двух переменных -- чтобы не делать два вычисления за проход цикла. Хотя...

Comment: А ещё какой-то идиот использует возведение в степень вместо умножения. Но всё-таки на будущее: как разбить переменные?

Comment: @Montreal, что Вы подразумеваете под "разбить переменные"?

Comment: случай когда 

     a = 2
     b = a
     a = 3
     print b # >>>3

Comment: оно выведет 2. Может у вас там не числа, а какие нибудь объекты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

мой вариант:

```
def find_closest_square(n):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    for i in xrange(1,n+1):
        (a,b) = (b, i ** 2)
        print a,b

 find_closest_square(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

В python размерность int ограничивается только ресурсами выделенными OS для Python Virtual Machine. Смысл ручном вычислении возведения в степень есть только при необходимости работы с промежуточными данными, например при их выводе на консоль.

Функция:

```
def find_closest_square(x):
    for i in range(x+1):
        print(i*i)
```

Вывод:

```
0
1
4
9
16
```

Comment: Ваш вывод не совпадает с тем, что @Montreal хочет.

Comment: @KoVadim, почитайте зачем @Montreal использует две переменных:

> Вообще суть введения двух переменных -- чтобы не делать два вычисления за проход цикла. Хотя...

То есть их наличие необязательно и является лишь ошибочной "оптимизацией" с его стороны.

Comment: На самом деле я вообще ушёл даалеко в сторону от решения оригинальной задачи, зачем-то начав использовать циклы. Да и вообще можно было просто посчитать на калькуляторе и округлить. Что-то я конкретно затупил.

Comment: И поэтому Вы решили поставить мне минус? Конечно, можно было написать что то вида

    for i in xrange(1, n):
        print (i-1)**2, i**2

И это даже понятнее. Но может у человека хитрый менеджер, который считает, что должна быть оптимизация?

Comment: Я поставил Вам минус потому что Вы не разобрались до конца чего конкретно желает пользователь, написать ответ и сделать мне замечание про некорректность реализации.

Comment: мой код решает задачу.

Comment: @KoVadim, которую Вы сами себе и придумали...

Comment: ещё раз прочитайте коментарий @Montreal, где он пишет 

 > В данном варианте она должна выдавать

Comment: @KoVadim, Я сдаюсь. Мы уже по второму кругу спорим.

Вы видите:

> В данном варианте она должна выдавать

Я вижу:

> Вообще суть введения двух переменных -- чтобы не делать два вычисления за проход цикла. Хотя...

Comment: Ребят, вопрос не стоит вашего спора. Виной всему мои ошибки. Во-первых, меня потянуло в циклы, хотя задачу можно решить элементарно сделав `import math`. Во-вторых, я ошибся, когда сделал `i ** i` вместо `i * i` или `i ** 2`.